# Number of words in n strings read from a file

Tags: c, string, file

So i am trying to determine number of words from n strings.The problem I have is that the when I read  the number of the strings from the file it somehow count as a string I guess.I am trying to get rid of the first line of the output but can't tell how.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>


int numar_cuvinte(char *propozitie, char *copie, int numar_propozitii, FILE *f)
{
    fgets(propozitie,49,f);


    strcpy(copie,propozitie);

    char *delimitatori = " ";
    char *token = strtok(copie,delimitatori);

    int numar_cuvinte = 0;

    while(token!=NULL)
    {

        numar_cuvinte++;
        token = strtok(NULL,delimitatori);
    }
    return numar_cuvinte;


}
int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    char*name_file = "in.txt";
    f=fopen(name_file,"r");
    if(f == NULL)
        printf("Can't oppen  %s",name_file);


    int nr_strings;;

    fscanf(f,"%d",&nr_strings);


    char *propozitie = (char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    char *copie = (char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= nr_strings ; i++)
            printf("String  : %s has %d words \n\n",propozitie,numar_cuvinte(propozitie,copie,nr_strings,f));



    free(propozitie);
    free(copie);
    fclose(f);


    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If `f == NULL`, it's not enough to just write a message.  You also need to stop processing.  But the message you write should be informative, and should be written to stderr.  eg `if( f == NULL) { perror( "in.txt"); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}`

Comment: Please do NOT post images of text. Copy and paste the text (indented by 4-spaces so it formats in fixed width).  What should have taken roughly 100 bytes to store as text, now requires 209,716 bytes as an image (204KB) That 209600% increase in storage requirement adds up quickly.